# Number too big for BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger

I'm developing a chemistry app, and I need to include the Avogadro's number:
 (`602200000000000000000000`)

I don't really know if I can use scientific notation to represent it as `6.022 x 10x23` (can't put the exponent).

I first used `double`, then `long` and now, I used `java.math.BigInteger`.

But it still says it's too big, what can I do or should this is just to much for a system?

Comment: If BigInteger says too big, you have to install more RAM.

Comment: The problem probably isn't BigInteger.  An integer of that size can be represented in about 80 bits.   Even allowing for other implementation overheads, BigInteger will support that with no problem.   The problem is probably how the OP is trying to do the initialisation.

Comment: In future instead of saying "it still says it's too big", just copy-paste the exact error message you see. For me the compiler says `integer number too large: 602200000000000000000000`.

Comment: What was wrong with using `double`?  The problem with `BigInteger` here is that your integer will include a lot of 0's that shouldn't be 0's.  The integer should really be `6023abcdefghijklmnopqrst`, where we don't know what any of those digits are except that `a < 5`, because the value is only accurate to 3 decimal places.  The intended use of `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` is to represent exact amounts like monetary values, for which `double` would be inappropriate.  But Avogadro's number is not an exact value.

Comment: Then again, if the problem was just that you didn't know how to write the exponent, Guffa has answered that for you.

Comment: @Takendarkk not true, from the docs: BigInteger constructors and operations throw ArithmeticException when the result is out of the supported range of -2^Integer.MAX_VALUE (exclusive) to +2^Integer.MAX_VALUE (exclusive).

Comment: @Aivean it's a joke since BigInteger is RAM based. Cool down.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, you need to check your physics / chemistry text book.

Avogadro's number is not 602,200,000,000,000,000,000,000.  It is *approximately* 6.022 x 10<sup>23</sup>.  The key word is "approximately".  As of 2019, the precise value is 6.02214076×10<sup>23</sup> mol<sup>−1</sup>

(In 2015 when I originally wrote this reply, the current best approximation for Avogadro's number was 6.022140857(74)×10<sup>23</sup> mol<sup>−1</sup>, and the relative error was +/- 1.2×10<sup>–8</sup>.  In 2019, the SI redefined the mole / Avogadro's number to be the precise value above.  Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant))

My original (2015) answer was that since the number only needed 8 decimal digits precision, the Java `double` type was an appropriate type to represent it.  Hence, I recommended:

```
final double AVOGADROS_CONSTANT = 6.02214076E23;
```

Clearly, neither `int` or `long` can represent this number.  A `float` could, but not with enough precision (assuming we use the best available measured value).

Now (post 2019) the `BigInteger` is the simplest correct representation.

---

Now to your apparent problems with declaring the constant as (variously) an `double`, a `long` and a `BigInteger`.

I expect you did something like this:

```
  double a = 602200000000000000000000;
```

and so on.  That isn't going to work, but the reason it won't work needs to be explained.  The problem is that the number is being supplied as an `int` literal.  An `int` cannot be that big.  The largest possible `int` value is 2<sup>31</sup> - 1 ... which is a little bit bigger than 2 x 10<sup>9</sup>.

That is what the Java compiler was complaining about.  The literal is too big to be an `int`.

It is too big for `long` literal as well.  (Do the math.)

But it is not too big for a `double` literal ... provided that you write it correctly.

The solution using `BigInteger(String)` works because it side-steps the problem of representing the number as a numeric literal by using a string instead, and parsing it at runtime.  That's OK from the perspective of the language, but (IMO) wrong because the extra precision is an illusion.

Answer (score 13):

Pass it to the BigInteger constructor as a `String`, and it works just fine.

```
BigInteger a = new BigInteger("602200000000000000000000");
a = a.multiply(new BigInteger("2"));
System.out.println(a);
```

Output: `1204400000000000000000000`

Comment: Thanks, seems like most of my program will be defined in String Arguments. But why does it can represent it as a string and yet it can't as an integer?

Comment: @AntonioAguilar it is because when you try to pass it to the BigInteger constructor like `BigInteger a = new BigInteger(602200000000000000000000);` then first that number gets parsed as an int. Obviously, though it won’t fit in an int, although it will certainly fit in a BigInt. To circumvent this, you pass the number as a String. See Dukeling’s answer for some more details.

Answer (score 6):

You can use E notation to write the scientific notation:

```
double a = 6.022e23;
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with how you're trying to create it (most likely), not because it can't fit.

If you have just a number literal in your code (even if you try to assign it to a `double` or `long`), [this is first treated as an integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) (before being converted to the type it needs to be), and the number you have can't fit into an integer.

```
// Even though this number can fit into a long, it won't compile, because it's first treated
// as an integer.
long l = 123456788901234;
```

---

To create a long, you can add `L` to your number, so `602200000000000000000000L`, although it won't fit into a long either - [the max value is 2<sup>63</sup>-1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

To create a double, you can add `.0` to your number, so `602200000000000000000000.0` (or `6.022e23` as Guffa suggested), although you should not use this if you want precise values, as you may lose some accuracy because of the way it stores the value.

To create a `BigInteger`, you can use [the constructor taking a string parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(java.lang.String)):

```
new BigInteger("602200000000000000000000");
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are using `long` to initialize BigInteger. Since `long` can represent 64-bit numbers, your number would be too big to fit in to `long`. Using `String` would help.